# How to trigger QueryTable AfterRefresh event after QueryTable.MaintainConnection is set to False?

Tags: excel, vba

My Power Query codes are as follows:

```
Dim connString As String, sSql As String, sourceshname As String, Filepath As String, qName As String
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim targetsh As Worksheet

sourceshname = "Sheet1"
targetsh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Filepath = C:\Users\PC\Documents\Book1.xlsx
qName = "QTable1"

    sSql = "SELECT * FROM [" & sourceshname & "$]"
    connString = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Filepath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""
    Set qt = targetsh.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connString, Destination:=targetsh.Range("A1"), Sql:=sSql)
    qt.Name = qName
    qt.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    qt.refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    qt.MaintainConnection = False
```

I had the qt.MaintainConnection set to False so that user can still access the source file to edit.

Now I ran into another problem where my AfterRefresh event stopped working due to `qt.MaintainConnection = False`. AfterRefresh event codes are as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MyQuery As queryTable

Private Sub MyQuery_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If Success Then
    
    MsgBox "Query has been refreshed."
    
    ' Declare variables
    Dim myRange As Range, myArr As Variant
    Dim Lastcol As Long, Lastrow As Long, j As Long
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Find last used range in header row
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim qt As queryTable
    
        For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each qt In WS.QueryTables
                If Not qt Is Nothing Then
                    WS.Activate
                    ' Assign header row to an array for loop
                    Set myRange = WS.Range("A1", Cells(Lastrow, Lastcol))
                    myArr = myRange
                        
                    ' Loop through the header row and replace "#" with "."
                    For j = LBound(myArr, 2) To UBound(myArr, 2)
                        myArr(1, j) = Replace(myArr(1, j), "#", ".")
                    Next j
                        
                    myRange = myArr
                    
                    qt.MaintainConnection = False
                End If
            Next qt
        Next WS
        
        Call sourceSheet.Activate            
    
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

Private Sub MyQuery_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)

    If MsgBox("Refresh query?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Cancel = True
    
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim qt As queryTable
    
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each qt In WS.QueryTables

        qt.MaintainConnection = True
        
        Next qt
    Next WS
    
End Sub
```

I tried inserting `qt.MaintainConnection = True` under BeforeRefresh event but it ain't helpful since the Query Table's connection was ended upon import. Any way to resolve this?